# Why does Azure create the 'DefaultResourceGroup-WEU' resource group and the log analytics workspace within?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am setting up the production environment/resource group for a project. Azure constantly creates a resource group called DefaultResourceGroup-WEU and places a DefaultWorkspace-bfcb05a5-938f-4336-9e3c-a5963f10acb7-WEU log analytics workspace in it. I tried creating a analytics workspace myself hoping it would stop doing it but it doesnt work.

It clutters up the organisation I want to achieve. Besides it being annoying.

Does someone know why Azure does this and how I can alter this behavior?

Comment: it is something that comes by default

Comment: Can this defaukt behavior be altered?

Answer (score 3):

If you are thinking why Azure is creating a resource group called **DefaultResourceGroup-XXX** where the XXX is related to your region and within that same resource group you have a **DefaultWorkspace-SubscriptionID-XXX** then it is most likely associated with **Azure Security Center**.

And yes we can change this behavior by logging on the Azure Security Center and in the *Workspace configuration* section, changing the default that is being configured, which is **Use workspace(s) created by Security Center (default)**. Follow the steps mentioned below to solve your problem.

- `Azure Security Center (ASC) > (Management) Pricing & settings > Select Subscription`.
- `ASC Settings > Auto provisioning > (Extensions) Log Analytics agent for Azure VMs > Edit configuration`.
- `Workspace configuration`.

There you will find two options

- Default workspace
- Different workspace

For more information read these [Azure Security Center & log Analytics Workspaces](https://guiltyspark.cloud/2019/04/15/azure-security-center-log-analytics-workspaces/) blog and [Configure auto provisioning for agents and extensions from Microsoft Defender for Cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/enable-data-collection#disable-auto-provisioning-) document.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found the setting. However the "Log Analytics agent for Azure VMs" extension is disabled at the moment. Can it be that something else generates the default resources?

Comment: Might it be an Azure Monitor component (e.g. Application Insights, which nowadays is backed by log analytics)?

Comment: In my case, this was auto-created when I created WebApp service.